# Dropdown menu not working using Kivy Language

Tags: python, binding, kivy, dropdown

I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu using only Kivy Language.

This program is a simple image that the user can resize, with a button that brings up a dropdown menu. When the program starts, part of the dropdown menu is appearing near the bottom. Other than that, everything looks right. When clicked, nothing happens, except the part of the dropdown menu that's visible (that I didn't want visible yet) disappears.

```
# .py file
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
# kivy.require('1.9.0') 

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# Creating widget class 
class SquareWidget(Widget):
    pass
# Creating Scatter Class 
class ScatterWidget(Scatter):
    do_rotation=False

# Create the layout class 
class Scatter_App(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class ScatterApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return Scatter_App()

if __name__=='__main__': 
    ScatterApp().run()
```

```
# .kv file
# Create the scatter properties        
<SquareWidget>:
    size: self.parent.size
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'image.jpg'  

<Scatter_App>:
    canvas: 
        Rectangle: 
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos 

    ScatterWidget: 
        id: square_widget_id 
        SquareWidget:

    DropDown:
        id: cdd
        Button:
            text: 'Item 1'
        Label:
            text: 'Item 2'
        Label:
            text: 'Item 3'

    Button:
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .2, .3, .85
        text: 'Choose'
        text_size: self.size
        text_pos: self.height/2,self.width/2
        size_hint: .15,.15
        pos: (self.parent.width-self.width)/2,self.parent.height-self.height
        on_release: cdd.open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

- If you add a `DropDown` directly in `kv`, it will become a child of `Scatter_App`, just like any other `Widget`. Then, trying to call `open()` on it will fail, because `open()` tries to do an `add_widget` (but the `DropDown` already has a parent).
- Your rule for the `DropDown` does not specify the height of each of the added `Widgets`. From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html#basic-example):

> When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually

- When calling `open()` on a `DropDown`, you must include an argument that specifies the `Widget` that the `DropDown` should attach to.

So, taking all this into account, I have created a slightly modified version of your `kv` file:

```
# .kv file
# Create the scatter properties     
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<SquareWidget>:
    size: self.parent.size
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'image.jpg'  

# add a dynamic class that extends DropDown
<MyDropDown@DropDown>:
    Button:
        text: 'Item 1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
    Label:
        text: 'Item 2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
    Label:
        text: 'Item 3'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40

<Scatter_App>:
    canvas: 
        Rectangle: 
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos 

    ScatterWidget: 
        id: square_widget_id 
        SquareWidget:

    Button:
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .2, .3, .85
        text: 'Choose'
        text_size: self.size
        text_pos: self.height/2,self.width/2
        size_hint: .15,.15
        pos: (self.parent.width-self.width)/2,self.parent.height-self.height
        on_release: Factory.MyDropDown().open(self)
```

I have added a `Factory` import to the `kv` file, so that you can create the `MyDropDown` in the `kv` file. I have also added `height` specifications to the `Widgets` added to the `DropDown`. The `MyDropDown.open()` call now includes `self` (the `Button`).